# How do I kill job in Sidekiq took long to finish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs, sidekiq, job-scheduling

I have jobs does it take more than 2h to finish. I want to put a time to limit how long it will take it. How do i can do?

Answer (score 7):

Wrap the logic with `Timeout::timeout` and disable retries if you don't want the job to be retried after a timeout.

```
class RunsTooLongWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options :retry => false

  def perform(*args)
    Timeout::timeout(2.hours) do
      # do possibly long running task
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You might have to rescue `Timeout::Error`.

Comment: It depends on whether you want the jobs to fail with `Timeout::Error` errors and whether you need to clean anything up before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ruby's timeout library to raise an error if it takes too long.

Comment: https://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/ probably not a good idea given this post

Comment: Why do you think I would recommend it in one thing and recommend against it in another?  Because "it depends" is really the answer and we don't have enough context to judge either way.